# C# ¿Como llamar a un método que devuelve LIST<estructura>?

Tags: c#, lista

Soy bastante nuevo en el tema. Supongo que se trata de una duda muy básica.
El método es:

```
public class CTablaFotos

{
    ....  
    public List<sEtiqueta> F1_Select_Etiquetas()
    {
        ...
        return "estructura tipo List<sEtiqueta>"
    }´´´
```

¿Como debería invocarlo desde el método principal? He probado así:

CTablaFotos **tablaFotos** = new CTablaFotos();

List lEtiquetes = **tablaFotos.F1_Select_Etiquetas()**; ==> error CS0029 no se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo...

Así, no da error:
**var resultado = tablaFotos.F1_Select_Etiquetas();** pero no sé como extraer los datos del VAR¿?

¿Qué debería poner?

**???????????? = tablaFotos.F1_Select_Etiquetas();**

Muchas gracias por adelantado!!!

Comment: tal cual como se declaró el método: `List<sEtiqueta> etiqueta=  tablaFotos.F1_Select_Etiquetas();`

Answer (score 0):

Debes invocarlo de la sigueinte manera:

```
CTablaFotos tablaFotos = new CTablaFotos();
List<sEtiqueta> lEtiquetes = tablaFotos.F1_Select_Etiquetas();
```

y para acceder a sus valores:

```
sEtiqueta Etiquete0= lEtiquetes[0];
sEtiqueta Etiquete1= lEtiquetes[1];
```

tambien podrias hacer un `Foreach`, todo en dependencias de lo que deseas hacer con los miembros de la lista devuelta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Eduardo

Comment: @JordiFornes Por nada, estamos aquí para ayudar, solo pedirte que si te resultó útil la respuesta, que la marques como aceptada y si lo crees justo que la puntees.